# Select box default value - only when no match in database (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

No biggie to set default value in a select box:

```
<option selected> MyOptionValue </option>
```

And for defaulting with a value from a database table ( here I read **years** from a table, and if the user record field **edu_end_year** gets a match I display that value as selected, if no match the default text is used ) :

```
<option value="default"> <?php echo $default_text_year ?> </option>
<?php while($option = $years->fetch_object()){ ?>
<option <?php echo $option->year == $record->edu_end_year ? 'selected' : ''?> value='<?php echo $option->year; ?>'> <?php echo $option->year ?></option> <?php } ?>
```

But I am stuck when it comes to combining the two in a code-efficient way. My question is this:

How do I set table record entry a default value only when there is no hit in the entries read from the user record? The value must come from the same table.

An example of implementation:

A user can select a favorite country from a list. 
When the user logs in the next time the favorised country should be shown as selected.
If no favorite country was selected, the user's home country should be shown as selected.

I am stuck. Any and all help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I'd probably use an if..else block to decide which of the two scenarios occur (Has the user selected a favorite country? If so, print out this list with a selected option. If not, print out that other list, with the default.

Comment: So first check in db for existing value, and the current code would go in the **IF** statement, and the second scenario in the **ELSE** statement? Could be worth a shot, but it would mean two blocks of code that are almost identical. I will be using the same functionality in quite a lot of places...

Comment: Try this one `<option <?php if($option->year == $record->edu_end_year ) {?> selected = 'selected' <?php }?> value='<?php echo $option->year; ?>'> <?php echo $option->year ?></option> ` if it works for you then revert me back

Comment: @NarendraSisodia - thanks, but how would this produce a different result (isn't it basically the same code)? I am quite new to programming so it is very possible that I am missing something.

Comment: Have you tried this code @Quoalquo